# How to install CPU-G on Version 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04

Do you know how to upload CPU-G onto Bionic Beaver version 18.04.1?  I need information about my computer for a Comp. Sci class.  Is there another program that I can use the will give me the same information?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from a 3rd party PPA and can still be installed.  Run the following from a terminal window:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cpu-g
```

The command `sudo apt update` may not be required due to when you run the first command in Ubuntu 18.04 it automatically should run the update line once the PPA is added.

Hope this helps!