# How to get CPU-G to run on 18.04

Tags: 18.04

What is necessary to get CPU-G to run on 18.04? I have performed all of the necessary steps I can find (see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433880/how-to-install-cpu-g-on-ubuntu) and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070279/how-to-install-cpu-g-on-version-18-04-1)) and searched the internet generally, to no avail.

Attempting to start the program using the Super key brings up the icon, but clicking the icon does nothing. Likewise, entering cpu-g in the Alt-F2 window also has no effect.

I'm sure this must be something really basic, but I don't have the skills to know what to look for.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find up-to-date information on `cpu-g`. In the meantime you might want to try `hardinfo` which you can install with:

```
sudo apt install hardinfo
```

Then typing `hardinfo` in the terminal or calling from Dash (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) the gui appears like this:

[image: hardinfo.png]

You can get most if not all the information you need from `cpu-g` plus a whole lot more information on your machine.

Comment: Thank you. I've installed it but it doesn't seem to say anything about installed software.

Comment: @Steev43230 listing installed software via GUI is covered by many apps. For example: `sudo apt install gnome-software`, `sudo apt install software-properties-gtk` and `sudo apt install synaptic`

Comment: I see now that you were suggesting an alternative. I did not realize that at first. What I was ultimately looking for from CPU-G was the nice JPG that CPU-Z gives you. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 7):

Let's see why it does not start:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/cpug/cpu-g-0.9.0.tar.gz
tar -xf cpu-g-0.9.0.tar.gz
cd cpu-g-0.9.0
```

Start it:

> ```
> $ ./cpu-g
> You need to have PyGTK 2.10.0, GTK.Glade and GTK+ 2.10.0 or higher             installed in your system in order to run CPU-G.
> ```

So it needs at least two packages to be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2 python-glade2
```

Then it will launch:

```
sudo ./cpu-g
```

> [image: CPU-G on 18.04 LTS]

(tested on VM and on real hardware)

---

About package from PPA ([`ppa:atareao/atareao`](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao?field.series_filter=bionic)) I also see that it does not start with:

> ```
> $ /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/cpu-g/bin/cpu-g
> [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'cpu-g'
> /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/cpu-g/share/cpu-g/distros/ubuntu.png
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/cpu-g/bin/cpu-g", line 42, in <module>
>       cpug = CPUG()
>   File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/cpu-g/share/cpu-g/cpug.py", line 999, in __init__
>       self.update_info()
>   File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/cpu-g/share/cpu-g/cpug.py", line 1318, in update_info
>       self.start_battery_updater()
>   File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/cpu-g/share/cpu-g/cpug.py", line 1346, in start_battery_updater
>       self.get_battery_duration()
>   File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/cpu-g/share/cpu-g/cpug.py", line 1079, in get_battery_duration
>       inv.battery_info('charge-now')/1000000) + _(' Ah'))
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
> ```

Comment: The CPU-G from SourceForge does not have desktop shortcut, so they do not interfere each other. But you can remove atareo's one with `sudo apt-get remove cpu-g` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: I removed the atareo one and installed python-gtk2 python-glade2.

It then ran, with the following output

cpu set to #0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cpu-g", line 330, in core_change
    self.wTree.get_object("l1data").set_text(main().sysdevcpu(index, 1, 'Data'))
  File "./cpu-g", line 141, in sysdevcpu
    print "Error: Cannot decide if the cores are %s or %s.\nUsing the lowest value as the real cores number." %(cpuinfo('coresnum','foo'), coresinsysdev) #FIXME: Wrong text. (?)
NameError: global name 'cpuinfo' is not defined [I don't know how to enter line breaks]

Comment: I have just tested it on real hardware and it works normally. So I can't reproduce the issue. You have to look for alternatives (as in first answer and maybe `lshw-gtk`).

Comment: I tried sudo-apt-get remove cpu-g to remove the sourceforge version, but it didn't see the program and so did not remove it. The sourceforge cpu-g hasn't been updated for years and only shows some information, so it's not helpful to me. How do I remove it?

Comment: Source version was downloaded to ~/Downloads folder. So you can simply remove the `cpu-g-0.9.0` folder from it.

Comment: Thank you, N0rbert.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is CPU-X

- https://thetumultuousunicornofdarkness.github.io/CPU-X/

On 18.04, if you want to use app-image instead of apt, one likely have to use version 4.3.1

- https://github.com/TheTumultuousUnicornOfDarkness/CPU-X/releases/tag/v4.3.1

Status on project:

- https://github.com/TheTumultuousUnicornOfDarkness/CPU-X/wiki/future-of-project

---

It looks similar to CPU-G but have no idea if there is any relation.

It also has `curses` and `dump` modes.

***GTK:***

[image: CPU-X GTK]

***Terminal:***

[image: CPU-X Curses]